# Issue while reading percentage value from xlsx using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am reading an xlsx file using apache poi jar through java.

The particular row of xlsx file reads as following on opening the xlsx file in MS-Excel:
[image]

When I try to read the highlighted value using poi, it gives me 0.1087091684032691

Both cell.toString() and cell.getNumericCellValue() are returning 0.1087091684032691 instead of 10.8709168403269%.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Kindly suggest what? ;) Percentages are stored as fractions. Just multiply by 100

Comment: Thanks Phil :) I was wondering if It is normal behavior to get a fraction value or not.